# Refactor class to function components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

[image: Results after attempting to search a term and location resulting in random results]I'm having a hard time converting these 3 class components to function components, the class components are working i just am trying to convert them for learning purposes.

the API call: yelp.js

```
const { default: SearchBar } = require("../components/SearchBar/SearchBar");

const Yelp = {
    searchYelp(term, location) {
        return fetch(`/api/hello?term=${term}&location=${location}`)
        .then((response) => {
            // console.log(response)
            return response.json()
        }).then((jsonResponse) => {
            // console.log(jsonResponse)
            if (jsonResponse.businesses) {
                return jsonResponse.businesses.map((business) => {
                    return {
                        id: business.id,
                        imageSrc: business.image_url,
                        name: business.name,
                        address: business.location.address1,
                        city: business.location.city,
                        state: business.location.state,
                        zipCode: business.location.zip_code,
                        category: business.categories.title,
                        rating: business.rating,
                        reviewCount: business.review_count,
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

export default Yelp
```

The Home component as a function that renders a SearchBar and BusinessList component: Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BusinessList from '../../../src/components/BusinessList/BusinessList';
import SearchBar from '../../../src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
import Yelp from '../../util/yelp';

const Home = (term, location) => {
    const [businesses, setBusinesses] = useState([]);

    const searchYelp = Yelp.searchYelp(term, location).then(businesses => {
        setBusinesses(businesses)
    })

    return (
        <>
            <SearchBar searchYelp={searchYelp} />
            <BusinessList business={businesses} />
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

The Home component as a class: Home.js

```
// import React from 'react';
// import BusinessList from '../../../src/components/BusinessList/BusinessList';
// import SearchBar from '../../../src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
// import Yelp from '../../util/yelp';

// class Home extends React.Component {
//     constructor() {
//         super();
//         this.state = {
//             businesses: [],
//         };

//         this.searchYelp = this.searchYelp.bind(this);
//     }

//     searchYelp(term, location, sortBy) {
//         Yelp.searchYelp(term, location, sortBy).then((businesses) => {
//             this.setState({ businesses: businesses })
//         })
//     }
//     render() {
//         return (
//             <>
//                 <SearchBar searchYelp={this.searchYelp} />
//                 <BusinessList businesses={this.state.businesses} />
//             </>
//         )
//     }
// }

// export default Home;
```

The BusinessList component as a function that renders a Business component: BusinessList.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './BusinessList.css';
import Business from '../Business/Business';

function BusinessList(businesses) {
    console.log(businesses)
    return (
            <div className="BusinessList">
                {
                businesses.map(business => {
                    <Business key={business.id} business={business} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
    )
};

export default BusinessList;
```

The BusinessList component as a class: BusinessList.js

```
// import React from 'react';
// import './BusinessList.css';
// import Business from '../Business/Business';

// class BusinessList extends React.Component {
//     constructor(props) {
//         super(props)
//         console.log(props.businesses)
//     }

//     render() {
//         return (
//             <div className="BusinessList">
//                 {
//                     this.props.businesses.map((business) => {
//                         return <Business key={business.id} business={business} />
//                     })
//                 }
//             </div>
//         )
//     }
// };

// export default BusinessList;
```

The Business component as a function: Business.js

```
import React from "react";
import './Business.css';

const Business = (business) => {
    return (
        <div className="Business">
            <div className="image-container">
                <img src={business.business.imageSrc} alt={business.imageSrc} />
            </div>
            <h2>{business.business.name}</h2>
            <div className="Business-information">
                <div className="Business-address">
                    <p>{business.business.address}</p>
                    <p>{business.business.city}&nbsp;{business.state}&nbsp;{business.zipCode}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Business-reviews">
                    <h3>{business.business.category}</h3>
                    <h3 className="rating">{business.business.rating}</h3>
                    <p>{business.business.reviewCount} reviews</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Business;
```

The Business component as a class: Business.js

```
// import React from "react";
// import './Business.css';

// class Business extends React.Component {
//     render() {
//         const { business } = this.props

//         return (
//             <div className="Business">
//                 <div className="image-container">
//                     <img src={business.imageSrc} alt={business.imageSrc} />
//                 </div>
//                 <h2>{business.name}</h2>
//                 <div className="Business-information">
//                     <div className="Business-address">
//                         <p>{business.address}</p>
//                         <p>{business.city}&nbsp;{business.state}&nbsp;{business.zipCode}</p>
//                     </div>
//                     <div className="Business-reviews">
//                         <h3>{business.category}</h3>
//                         <h3 className="rating">{business.rating}</h3>
//                         <p>{business.reviewCount} reviews</p>
//                     </div>
//                 </div>
//             </div>
//         )
//     }
// };

// export default Business;
```

EDIT **
My attempt at SearchBar component as function: SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './SearchBar.css';

const SearchBar = (props) => {
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('')
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('best_match')

    const sortByOptions = {
        'Best Match': 'best_match',
        'Highest Rated': 'rating',
        'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
    };

    const handleSortByChange = () => {
        setSortBy(sortBy)
        // console.log(sortByOption)
        console.log(sortBy)
    }

    const renderSortByOptions = (sortByOptions) => {
        // console.log(Object.keys(sortByOptions))
        return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
            let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption]
            // console.log(sortByOptionValue)
            return <li
                className={sortBy === sortByOption ? 'active' : ''}
                onClick={handleSortByChange}
                key={sortByOptionValue}>
                {sortByOption}
            </li>;
        })
    }

    const handleTermChange = (event) => {
        setTerm(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleLocationChange = (event) => {
        setLocation(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.searchYelp(term, location)
    }

    return (
        <div className="SearchBar">
            {props.searchYelp}
            <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
                <ul>
                    {renderSortByOptions(sortByOptions)}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="SearchBar-fields">
                <input
                    onChange={handleTermChange}
                    placeholder="Search Businesses"
                />
                <input
                    onChange={handleLocationChange}
                    placeholder="Where?"
                />
                <button className="SearchBar-submit" onClick={handleSearch}>Let's Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

EDIT**
SearchBar component as a class: SearchBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: '',
            location: '',
            sortBy: 'best_match'
        }

        this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)
        this.handleLocationChange = this.handleLocationChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)

        this.sortByOptions = {
            'Best Match': 'best_match',
            'Highest Rated': 'rating',
            'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
        };
    }

    getSortByClass(sortByOption) {
        // console.log(sortByOption)
        if (this.state.sortBy === sortByOption) {
            return 'active'
        }
        return ''
    }

    handleSortByChange(sortByOption) {
        this.setState({
            sortBy: sortByOption
        })
    }

    handleTermChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            term: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleLocationChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            location: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSearch(event) {
        this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy)
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    renderSortByOptions() {
        return Object.keys(this.sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
            let sortByOptionValue = this.sortByOptions[sortByOption]
            console.log(sortByOptionValue)
            return <li
                onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)}
                className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
                key={sortByOptionValue}>
                {sortByOption}
            </li>;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchBar">
                {this.searchYelp}
                <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
                    <ul>
                        {this.renderSortByOptions()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="SearchBar-fields">
                    <input onChange={this.handleTermChange} placeholder="Search Businesses" />
                    <input onChange={this.handleLocationChange} placeholder="Where?" />
                    <button className="SearchBar-submit" onClick={this.handleSearch}>Let's Go</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I keep getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
Or the error "Businesses.map is not a function"

Im also a little confused as to why when everything is converted to function components in my final Business component in order to get things to showup im required to pass things in as business.business.imageSrc instead of just business.imageSrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in `Home` `searchYelp` should be declared as a function so it can be passed as a callback to the `SearchBar` component.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [businesses, setBusinesses] = useState([]);

  const searchYelp = (term, location) => {
    Yelp.searchYelp(term, location)
      .then(businesses => {
        setBusinesses(businesses);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar searchYelp={searchYelp} />
      <BusinessList business={businesses} />
    </>
  )
};
```

Then in `BusinessList` you need to access the passed `business` prop. Your current code is naming the props object `businesses` and then attempts to map it. It could be `businesses.business.map`, but by convention we name the props object `props` or simply destructure the props you want to use. You need to also return the `Business` component you are mapping to.

```
function BusinessList({ business }) {
  return (
    <div className="BusinessList">
      {business.map(business => {
        return <Business key={business.id} business={business} />;
      })}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Same issue with the props object name in the `Business` component.

```
const Business = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="Business">
      <div className="image-container">
        <img src={props.business.imageSrc} alt={props.business.imageSrc} />
      </div>
      <h2>{props.business.name}</h2>
      <div className="Business-information">
        <div className="Business-address">
          <p>{props.business.address}</p>
          <p>{props.business.city}&nbsp;{props.business.state}&nbsp;{business.zipCode}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="Business-reviews">
          <h3>{props.business.category}</h3>
          <h3 className="rating">{props.business.rating}</h3>
          <p>{props.business.reviewCount} reviews</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this Drew, <SearchBar searchYelp={searchYelp} /> passing in searchYelp returns as undefined so i tried to do <SearchBar searchYelp={Yelp.searchYelp} /> which did render, but still makes the searchBar not work... Its console logging the search result but not displaying it to the DOM. It's also returning random search results on page load without entering a search

Comment: @Halp_am_stuck Oh, I see, you are wanting to pass a callback to the `SearchBar`. Let me adjust. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Something is still not working right...  on search im getting back a fetched api call with undefined passed into location and term in the url. I wouldn't think the SearchBar component would affect these but ill update my answer to reflect the SearchBar component code

Comment: @Halp_am_stuck Yes, seeing what the `SearchBar` is doing with the passed prop would be helpful.

Comment: @Halp_am_stuck Where are `location` and `term` undefined? `handleSearch` in `SearchBar`? `searchYelp` in `Home`? In the `Yelp.searchYelp` utility?

Comment: Sorry, in Yelp.js the file making the fetch api call (the utility file)

Comment: @Halp_am_stuck So they are defined in `searchYelp` in `Home`? but then undefined in the Yelp.js file?

Comment: No in Home they are random search results not pertaining to a location or term that was searched. I added an image in the post

Comment: I got it! we forgot to pass in term, location into the searchYelp function in Home.js.. i guess i should say I your solution already shows that i dont know how i missed that

Answer (score 1):

`BusinessList` receives `props`, an object *containing* the props passed in.

The function parameter would either need to destructure it:

```
function BusinessList({ businesses }) { ... }
```

Or reference it off the `props` object:

```
function BusinessList(props) {
  console.log(props.businesses)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few notes:

- Right now `Yelp.searchYelp` returns `Promise<any[] | undefined>`, i.e `undefined` is a legitimate value that the consume may get. Up to you to decide if `setBusinesses(businesses)` when `businesses` is undefined is useful or not, but in that case, handle it. Otherwise default to an empty array, `setBusinesses(businesses ?? [])` or throw an error.
- Do not run side effects in the render phase, i.e call the api inside a `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const searchYelp = Yelp.searchYelp(term, location).then(businesses => {
        setBusinesses(businesses ?? [])
    })
}, [term, location])
```

- Lastly, `const Business = (business) => {` here `business` is actually the props object. You can simply destructure it `const Business = ({ business }) => {` to get the value directly.

Comment: ?? [] i'm not familiar with this syntax... is this like a weird react conditional similar to a ternary operator?

Comment: it's just the coalescing operator. syntax sugar for (mostly) `businesses ? businesses : []`